# Position absolute doesnt have fixed place on scroll

Tags: html, css, position, css-position, absolute

So I was trying to make a music app and had my position absolute mess up the whole layout when I scroll

I tried searching on the internet about keeping parent position:relative but didnt work

My HTML-

```
<div style="width:inherit;height:inherit;overflow:hidden" >
  <div class="ov" ><div><i style="font-size:2em;" class="fa fa-pause-circle"></i></div></div>
```

My CSS-

```
.ov{

    width:12em;
    overflow: hidden;

    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    flex-direction: column;

    border-radius: 15px;
    height: 12em;
    opacity:0.8;
    position: absolute;
    z-index:2;
    background-color: black;

}
```

How it should look - (https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPTBK.jpg)
How it looks when I scroll - (https://i.stack.imgur.com/TGgyT.jpg)

Comment: you mean that it should position on the image?

Comment: you can set the first div to absolute and the .ov to relative

Comment: if you can create a snippet or you can post your code so we can test it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

give the  first div position:absolute; and its better to give it and id or class and then .ov{position:relative} ;

```css
.ov{

    width:12em;
    overflow: hidden;

    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    flex-direction: column;

    border-radius: 15px;
    height: 12em;
    opacity:0.8;
    position: relative;
    z-index:2;
    background-color: black;

}
```

```html
<div style="position:absolute;width:inherit;height:inherit;overflow:hidden" >
  <div class="ov" ><div><i style="font-size:2em;" class="fa fa-pause-circle"></i></div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you trying to make an object not scroll the with website you use `position:fixed;`

Position:absolute just aligns an object based off of the nearest container with position:relative.